# How to send parameters in request payload conditionally in reactjs and Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have below request body,

```
const requestbody = {
    "applicationname":"app1",
    "applicationtype":"permenant",
    "startDate":"24 march",
    "endDate":"30 march",
    "refreshtime":""    
}
```

I need to send "startDate" and "endDate" to backend only if its value is nonempty like

```
const requestbody = {
    "applicationname":"app1",
    "applicationtype":"permenant",
    "startDate":"24 march",
    "endDate":"30 march",
    "refreshtime":"",
    
}
```

else request body should be

```
const requestbodywithoutdate = {
    "applicationname":"app1",
    "applicationtype":"permenant",
    "refreshtime":30
    
}
```

Comment: Please include the code that's making the request.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is doing something like:

```
const requestbody = {
    "applicationname":"app1",
    "applicationtype":"permenant",
    ...(startDate ? { startDate } : {}),
    ...(endDate   ? { endDate   } : {}),
    "endDate":"30 march",
    "refreshtime":"",
}
```

Assuming `startDate` is a string containing `24 march` and `endDate` a string containing `30 march`.

I used here a string as boolean, but it's up to you to replace `startDate ?` by somthing like `values.startDate ?` or other condition resulting to a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

You can use lodash to exclude it.

`const requestBody = _.omitBy(myObject, _.isNil)`